# Отправка объекта JS в БД

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Нужно,чтобы при нажатии на класс .btn добавить в .container блок test со значениями из объекта JS, а затем эти данные как-то отправить в базу данных для дальнейшей обработки.

К сожалению, не знаю с чего начать. Понял лишь одно: нужно оправить ajax запрос 
что-то вроде этого:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {

    }
```

Объект засунуть в JSON. Но куда пихать этот AJAX код, как связать с переменной water, что писать в PHP коде - без понятия.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь - ссылки, возможно какие-то другие решения.

```js
var water = {
  name: 'water',
  count: 200
};
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').append(
    `<div class='test'>\n<div class='test__name'>${water.name}</div>\n<div class='test__price'>${water.count}</div>\n</div>`
  );
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  background-color: #2a66ad;
}

.test {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="test">
    <div class="test__name">

    </div>
    <div class="test__price">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: (со значениями из массива) что за массив (эти данные)что такое эти

Comment: @qwabra, прошу прощения, я имел ввиду данные из объекта.

Comment: всё равно не понятно. имеется ввиду `water.name` `water.count` ?

Comment: @qwabra, да. Нужно передать как-то их значения в бд

Comment: ещё две вещи меня смущают: почему именно php+mysql. как альтернатива nodejs/php+sqlite/json/csv

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, тут достаточно просто, почитай эту [статью](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81). Это неофициальная документация, но для понимания может сгодиться. Чтобы отправить ajax на сервер, достаточно в обработчике клика по кнопке `.btn` (хотя я бы рекомендовал не смешивать оформление с логикой - т.е. для стилей свои классы, а для js логики свои, например с префиксом `.js-`)

Разметка `index.html` со скриптом

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn js-btn">Кнопка</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="test">
        <div class="test__name">

        </div>
        <div class="test__price">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var water = {
        name: 'water',
        count: 200
    };
    // обработчик клика по кнопке
    $('.js-btn').on('click', function() {
        // добавляешь данные в разметку сразу же
        $('.container').append(
            `<div class='test'>
                <div class='test__name'>${water.name}</div>
                <div class='test__price'>${water.count}</div>
            </div>`
        );

        // отправляешь ajax запрос на сервер
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php', //url серверного обработчика
            type: 'POST', // тип запроса 
            data: water, // объект с данными берем из замыкания
            beforeSend: ()=>{}, //этот коллбэк выполняется перед отправкой запроса
            // этот обработчик выполняется, когда сервер присылает 
            // успешный ответ
            success: (data)=>{
                // data - это тело ответа сервера
                console.log(data);
            },
            // этот коллбэк выполняется, когда сервер присылает ошибку (коды 300+)
            error: (xhr)=>{
                console.log(xhr);
            },
            // этот коллбэк выполнится в любом случае - при успешном и неуспешном запросе
            complete: ()=>{
                // какие-то действия
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Серверный обработчик `test.php` (будет работать, если в одной директории)

```
<?php
// подключение к бд
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');
// в данном примере запрос очень сырой и неподготовленный
// обязательно изучи вопрос фильтрации данных перед вставкой в БД (гуглится)
$name = $_POST['name']; //поле name из переданного объекта js
$count = $_POST['count'];
$query = "INSERT INTO table (`name`,`count`) VALUES ('{$name}','{$count}')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// вывести результат
print_r($result);
```

Comment: А это нормально, что выдает ошибку 404(Браузер не видит index.php)? Из-за POST запроса. Если поставить GET, то все нормально.

Comment: расставь все по полочкам. Клиентская часть отдельно, серверная отдельно. посмотри обновленную разметку